# In R, create a variable using counts of events in a date range

Tags: r, date, dplyr

**Background**

I've got an `R` dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b", "c","c","c"),
                event = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2013-04-07","2014-07-14")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

As you can see, it's got 3 distinct people in the `ID` column, and they've either had or not had an `event`, along with a date their event status was recorded (`event_date`).

**The Problem**

I'd like to create a new variable / column, `event_within_interval`, which assigns 1 to *all* the cells of a given `ID` if that `ID` has 2 or more `event`=1 within 180 days of their *first* `event`=1.

Let me explain further: both `ID=a` and `ID=c` have 2 or more events each, but only `ID=c` has their **second** event within 180 days of their first (so here, the 4/7/2013 - 3/14/2013 = 24 days for `ID=c`).

The problem is that I'm not sure how to tell `R` this idea of "if the second happens within 180 days of the first `event=1`".

**What I'd like**

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
want <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c"),
                event = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2013-04-07","2014-07-14")),
                event_within_interval = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**What I've tried**

I've only got the beginnings of an attempt thus far:

```
d <- d %>% 
  mutate(event_within_interval = ID %in% if_else(d$event == 1, 1, 0))
```

But this doesn't give me what I'd like, as you can tell if you run the code.

I've set the thing up as an `if_else`, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

**UPDATE**: I've edited both reproducible examples (what I've got and what I want) to emphasize the fact that the desired date interval needs to be between the first event and the second event, not the first event and the last event. (A couple of users submitted examples using `last`, which worked for the previous iteration of the reproducible example but wouldn't have worked on the real dataset.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good fun.

## Scenario 1

My approach would be to

- group events by `ID`
- Apply first condition check on two the span of days between current date and initial date
- check if the sum of events is bigger or equal two: `sum(event) >= 2`
- only if the two conditions are met I would return one for the event

*For readability, I've returned values of conditions in the data as `test_*` variables.*

---

```
  d %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(test_interval = event_date - min(event_date) < 180,
           test_sum_events = sum(event) >= 2,
           event_within_interval = if_else(test_interval & test_sum_events, 
                                           1, 0)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

### Scenario 2

In this scenario, the data is sorted by `event_date` within `ID` and the difference between the first event and second event has to be under 180 days. Rest of events is ignored.

```
d %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    arrange(event_date) %>%
    mutate(
        # Check the difference between first event: min(event_date) and
        # second event: event_date[2]
        test_interval_first_two = event_date[2] - min(event_date) <= 180,
        test_sum_events = sum(event) >= 2,
        event_within_interval = if_else(
          test_interval_first_two & test_sum_events, 1, 0)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Glad someone's having fun with this (it wasn't me!). I'm going to try and implement this now -- I'm getting hung up on telling R to look at each person's *second* event, not their *last*.

Comment: @logjammin So I was initially thinking about using `lag` and ordering your data by event date; however, we would probably need to refine your requirement a little. Are you looking at *the difference has to be under 180 days between **first** and **whatever** event* or are you looking at the *difference between **consecutive events**?* In the second option`lag` and sorting are appropriate; in the approach order doesn't matter as it works `min(event_date) # aka first event # - current_event`.

Comment: Great question -- it's the difference between **a person's first two consecutive event=1's**. Doesn't matter if someone has 27 total `event=1`'s: if the first two events occur within 180 days of each other, then every row that person has should be marked `1` in `event_within_interval`. Does that help? Apologies if not, happy to keep trying!

Comment: Yep, Scenario 2 looks like the winner. It certainly works on my toy example exactly as I needed it to. I'm going to port it over to my real dataset now and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

What about by packages `lubridate` and `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b", "c","c"),
                event = c(1,1,0,0,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2013-04-07")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d <-  data.table(d)

d <- d[, event_within_interval := 0]

timeInterval <- interval(start = "2013-03-14", end = "2013-04-07")

d <- d[event == 1 & event_date %within% timeInterval, event_within_interval := 1]

d
#    ID event event_date event_within_interval
# 1:  a     1 2011-01-01                     0
# 2:  a     1 2012-08-21                     0
# 3:  b     0 2011-12-23                     0
# 4:  b     0 2011-12-31                     0
# 5:  c     1 2013-03-14                     1
# 6:  c     1 2013-04-07                     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `group_by` the `ID` column, so that we can calculate days within the same `ID`. Then in the condition in the `if_else` statement, use condition with `sum() > 1` AND day difference `<= 180`.

Here I assume there's only two "events" or rows per `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(event_within_interval = if_else(sum(event) > 1 & last(event_date) - first(event_date) <= 180, 1L, 0L))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    event event_date event_within_interval
  <chr> <dbl> <date>                     <int>
1 a         1 2011-01-01                     0
2 a         1 2012-08-21                     0
3 b         0 2011-12-23                     0
4 b         0 2011-12-31                     0
5 c         1 2013-03-14                     1
6 c         1 2013-04-07                     1
```

Comment: "Here I assume there's only two "events" or rows per ID." In the real dataset, there are many IDs who could have way more than 2 events, just FYI. Not sure if that changes your code -- but I'm gonna try it out now and modify the toy df to make ID c have 4 or 5 events.

Comment: And out of curiosity: what are that `1L` and `0L` doing there? Are you just forcing each date difference to be an integer?

Comment: 1. Since there are plenty of answers provided by other users, I will not update my answer. 2. In R, a number with a capital letter `L` indicates integer. Check out `class(1)` and `class(1L)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we could do it. In this example with an additional column `interval` to see the interval and then use an `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dpylr)

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(interval = last(event_date)- first(event_date),
         event_within_interval = ifelse(event == 1 &
                                          interval < 180, 1, 0))
```

```
  ID    event event_date interval event_within_interval
  <chr> <dbl> <date>     <drtn>                   <dbl>
1 a         1 2011-01-01 598 days                     0
2 a         1 2012-08-21 598 days                     0
3 b         0 2011-12-23   8 days                     0
4 b         0 2011-12-31   8 days                     0
5 c         1 2013-03-14  24 days                     1
6 c         1 2013-04-07  24 days                     1
```

Comment: This works on the toy dataset, for sure (and thanks!), but it wouldn't work on the real dataset since there would be, in many cases, more than just two events per ID. So we'd need the `interval` to be the difference between the first `event_date` and the second -- not the last.

Comment: This is no problem. Maybe you could provide a reproducible example. In essence it could be done by grouping. And you should not provide pictures. Instead use `dput(yourdataframe)` and copy the output and paste it to your question as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See the 2 new reproducible examples in the updated post. You'll see ID=c now has 3 entries: the last entry is too far from the 1st (beyond 180 days) but the second entry is within 180 days. I need to use the second entry.